# Looking for a good book on Rebbe Akiva ben Joseph's life

Tags: product-recommendation, rabbi-akiva-ben-yosef, biography

I was reading about [Rebbe Akiva ben Joseph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akiva_ben_Joseph) and became intrigued by his life and his ideas.

I'd like to read a book about him that covers his life and details his contributions to ethics, etc.

Would appreciate any references.

Notes:

1. I'm a secular humanist and I'm looking for a text that does justice to Rebbe Akiva from a secular point of view -- I'm still interested in Jewish tradition's narrative of the supernatural or metaphysical aspects of the Rebbe's life -- but I'd also like to understand his contributions in the wider Human context
2. I'm not Jewish -- am an Atheist -- of one the other Monotheistic faith's heritage.

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya! Thanks for sharing your question. Consider taking the following short [tour](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/tour) to learn more about the site. This site is available to all; your religion makes no difference! Perhaps therefore consider [editing](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/posts/61752/edit) your this out of the question, thus making the question more general and less personal.

Comment: @mevaqesh -- many thanks for the note -- the reason I put down my background is that it may help in the recommendation of the text to me -- I'm a secular humanist and I'm looking for a text that does justice to Rebbe Akiva from a secular point of view -- I'm still interested in Jewish tradition's narrative of the supernatural or metaphysical aspects of the Rebbe's life -- but I'd also like to understand his contributions in the wider Human context -- do you feel I should still edit the question?

Comment: That seems like a good thing to edit in, indeed.

Comment: @mevaqesh I edited the question some to move the personal into the notes -- hope that helps -- thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the best book but it is a nice read http://www.amazon.com/Akiba-story-Rabbi-his-times/dp/B0007I4HMW/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1438693257&sr=8-1&keywords=Akiva%2C+The+Story+of+Rabbi+Akiva+and+his+Times

Comment: @Danno many thanks for the note -- I saw that book but was not sure if it was suitable for what I was looking for. Thanks again

Comment: @Danno, if you post this as an answer I'll accept it. Thanks.

Comment: The "secular humanist" viewpoint of Rabbi Akiva does not do him justice. He cannot be understood except from the (Jewish) religius aspect.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the request specifically asks for an invalid ("secular humanist") viewpoint.

Comment: @sabbahillel That's not why I voted to close. I voted because this isn't a question about Judaism. (See the above close reason: "Questions about [...] Jewish individuals [...] *except as related to Judaism*, are [off-topic](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1473).")

Comment: @Shokhet The request for a non-Jewish viewpoint applies to *except as related to Judaism* so I would agree with you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only book I know on the subject (and which we used to use in the classroom) is [http://www.amazon.com/Akiba-story-Rabbi-his-times/dp/B0007I4HMW/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1438693257&sr=8-1&keywords=Akiva%2C+The+Story+of+Rabbi+Akiva+and+his+Times](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0007I4HMW)

though we also used [http://www.amazon.com/As-Driven-Leaf-Milton-Steinberg/dp/0874419506](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0874419506) which deals (somewhat as fiction) with R. Akiva as a side character.